# Keeping HTML list items inline and overlaying text

Tags: html, css

I need some help understanding how to solve this problem. I've got multiple list elements that each have text with an unknown length. On each side of this text, there will be a small image/icon. Here is an example of the HTML:

```css
.truncate>img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Content
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul id="myList" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" value="">
          <div class="truncate">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Close_Box_Red.png">A long text string that is about this length
            <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/4/b/11949892282132520602led_circle_green.svg.med.png">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" value="">
          <div class="truncate">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Close_Box_Red.png">A long text string that is about this length
            <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/4/b/11949892282132520602led_circle_green.svg.med.png">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" value="">
          <div class="truncate">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Close_Box_Red.png">A long text string that is about this length
            <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/4/b/11949892282132520602led_circle_green.svg.med.png">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6jxv3mj/).

I want the text to have an ellipsis at the end if it is longer than the available width. I know how to use text-overflow: ellipsis and I can get the text to have an ellipsis but only after the right image drops below the text.

**Some things that I have tried:**

- I have tried surrounding the whole li element in a div and using
  display: inline-block
- Similarly, I've tried surrounding just the image tags and text in a
  single div with inline-block which has been closest to the desired result.
- I tried putting the text in a span element and various CSS styling.

Each time the right image still jumps below the text.

Desired result:

[image]

And actual result:

[image]

Let me know if I should include any other information. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Without knowing your CSS, a solution comes to mind: Use padding on the right of the <li> in combination with `box-sizing: border-box;`, and include the image as absolutely positioned. HOWEVER, having your CSS, or better yet, a representative JsFiddle, would be best.

Comment: @BenPhilipp, That almost works! Could I haven't ever really used the box-sizing attribute so I'll look up information related to that. But by doing what you said, now the images are all fixed at the end of the text and not floating to the right. I'll see if I can get another screenshot and post it.

Comment: I've just seen your jsfiddle, and it works well in my browser. Which one are you using?

Comment: That might be something with the position being absolute I guess.. I'm not the best with CSS.

Comment: The jsFiddle works semi well, but I don't want the right image to be truncated with ellipses, just the text. I always want to be able to see both images but the amount of text would depend on the width.

Comment: Just out of interest: You say "fixed at the end of the text and not floating to the right" - what exactly do you mean, visually? Your desired example has the image sticking to the right as well. Do you mean for instances where the text is shorter? Simply tell it to be 100% wide, or a pixel value

Comment: @BenPhilipp, Sorry I wasn't more specific. The images were being fixed to the length of the text so they weren't vertically aligned with each other. I didn't try using a 100% width on the list element but that seems like it would have worked because everything else was working well. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick could be to manually position the images on left and right and then place the text inside an absolutely-positioned div:

```css
.left { position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
}

.right { position: absolute;
         right: 0px;
}

.text { position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        left: 24px;
        right: 24px;
}

.container { display: inline-block;
             width: 100%;
             position: relative;
             height: 24px;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="container">
          <img class="left" src="http://raksy.dyndns.org/cross.png">
          <div class="text">
            This is a text
          </div>
          <img class="right" src="http://raksy.dyndns.org/disc.png">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="container">
          <img class="left" src="http://raksy.dyndns.org/cross.png">
          <div class="text">
            This is a much longer text that most probably will have to be truncated
          </div>
          <img class="right" src="http://raksy.dyndns.org/disc.png">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="container">
          <img class="left" src="http://raksy.dyndns.org/cross.png">
          <div class="text">
            This is a text (somewhat longer but not huge)
          </div>
          <img class="right" src="http://raksy.dyndns.org/disc.png">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: This seems to be working, I'll implement it in my code and post my results!

Comment: This works pretty well! Have to change some padding on a few elements but it does exactly what I want. I definitely need to look up more information on position relative and absolute. Also with display attributes. But thanks! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a div wrapper, including `display: inline-block`, and it worked well:

http://jsfiddle.net/nozimica/y3oy723v/

The key is:

- Create a div wrapper.

  - Assign `display: inline-block;`
  - Give it a width.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not 100% what you want, but may get you the rest of the way:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hx6r748b/1/)

```
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;    
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.list-group-item{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    padding:0px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats work, and so does absolute positioning:

```
.truncate>img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
}

.truncate img:first-child {
  right: 8px;
  left: auto;
}

.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

<li class="list-group-item" value="">
  <div class="truncate">
    <img src="...">
    <img src="..."> A long text string that is about this length
  </div>
</li>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/p6jxv3mj/4/)**